# How do I move this account-bound booster to an alt?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Most of my characters got boosters on my account anniversary, including one character who's too high in level to take advantage. I would like to move the account-bound booster from that character to one of my low-level alts that *didn't* get one, but I don't see any way to send this to my bank. How do I go about this?

Comment: The easiest way to access your bank is to look for the "sack of money" icon in any of the major cities (well, currently Gendarran Fields is substituting for Lion's Arch services) and talk to the NPC with that icon above his/her head. This storage is shared between your characters. Alternatively, some people send an in-game mail to a friend and ask them to "return to sender" (so they can pick up the mail item with a different alt), though that could be considered abusing the mail system, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: you should be able to take the booster directly from your inventory and place it in your bank. IIRC, I went to an actual bank and drag and drop. That should work for you, because I did that myself haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put the birthday boosters into my bank by receiving the mail (take-all) and then putting the package into the bank, either through a crafting station or bank access NPC.